# A proof involving the zero element of a vector space and the zero element of a field.

Tags: vector-spaces

Let $V$ be some vector space and $F$ some field. How does one go about proving, rigorously, that $0_F0_V=0_V$. Where $0_F$ denotes the zero element of $F$ and $0_V$ denotes the zero element of $V$.

Answer (score 0):

$0_F0_v+0_F0_v=(0_F+0_F)0_v=0_F0_v
\Rightarrow 0_F0_v+0_F0_v-0_F0_v=0_v\Rightarrow 0_F0_v=0_v $

Answer (score 0):

You have

$$ 0_V = 0_F \cdot 0_V + (-(0_F \cdot 0_V)) \\ 
= ((0_F + 0_F) \cdot 0_V) + (-(0_F \cdot 0_V)) \\
= ((0_F \cdot 0_V) + (0_F \cdot 0_V)) + (-(0_F \cdot 0_V)) \\
= (0_F \cdot 0_V) + ((0_F \cdot 0_V) + (-(0_F \cdot 0_V))) \\
= 0_F \cdot 0_V + 0_V \\
= 0_F \cdot 0_V.
$$

Each equality is justified by one of the axioms for a vector space (or a field). As a good exercise, check that you understand which axiom justifies each equality.